# Search text for geocoding Kapellskär harbour

Tags: here-api

We have difficulties geocoding a specific location, what would be an appropriate searchtext parameter to use to geocode the "Kapellskär" harbour? The harbour can be found in wego.here.com when searching for "Kapellskärs hamn, E18, SE-760 15 Norrtälje"

We have tried with:

- Kapellskärs hamn, E18, SE-760 15 Norrtälje
- E18, 76015 KAPELLSKÄR, SWEDEN
- 76015 KAPELLSKÄR, SWEDEN
- Kappelskär 1, 76015 GRÄDDÖ, SWEDEN
- Terminalbyggnaden, 76015 KAPELLSKÄR, SWEDEN
- Gräddö, 76015 KAPELLSKÄR, SWEDEN
- Finnlink, 76015 GRÄDDÖ, SWEDEN

Example request:

https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=E18%2C%2076015%20KAPELLSK%C3%84R%2C%20SWEDEN&app_id=devportal-demo-20180625&app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ&gen=9

Closest we get is 3km away, which is close but not close enough. The harbour is a bit special since it doesn't have a street address, besides E18, which is 1890km long.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using Micro Point Unit Addressing for GeoCoder API

> https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=E18%2C%2076015%20KAPELLSK%C3%84R%2C%20SWEDEN&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxxx&gen=9&additionaldata=IncludeMicroPointAddresses,true&locationattributes=mapReference

Please refer below document for more reference 
developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/example-geocode-find-address-with-micropointaddress.html

Comment: I tried that but it seems to have no effect, still about 3km away from target. The documentation says that "This feature is available in the United States of America, Australia and New Zealand", perhaps that's why it had no effect?